# Django dropdown divider

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a dropdown menu that i generated by looping through a list of objects. I have a divider after object 0, 10, and 13. However some user don't have access to all objects so the dividers dont show. Can someone suggest a good way have after the last object in each bucket. I.e. bucket [0], [1-10], [11-13]. They buckets are areas in different states.

I'm not necessarily asking for someone to write the code for me. I'm just asking how to do this conceptually as I'm quite new to coding and Django. Any help is much appreciated!

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for i in area_list %}
        {% if not i.area_id == area.area_id %}
            {% if i.area_id == 0 or i.area_id == 10 or i.area_id == 13 %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'market_overview' area_id=i.area_id %}">{{ i.area_name }}</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'market_overview' area_id=i.area_id %}">{{ i.area_name }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for).  Try:

```
context['zones'] = (area_list[:1], area_list[1:11], area_list[11:])
```

and:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for areas in zones %}
        {% for i in areas %}
            {% if not i.area_id == area.area_id %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'market_overview' area_id=i.area_id %}">{{ i.area_name }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <li class="divider"></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can also prepare the zones and filter empty zones in your view.